# Update text on a tkinter window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

How would I go about making it so I can add more text on a already open tkinter window without having remove the previous text or replacing the previous text with the new text?

Here is my code so far:

```
def display_text():
    class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

        def __init__(self):
            tk.Tk.__init__(self)
            self.label = tk.Label(self, text='Enter text')
            self.label.pack(side = 'top', pady = 5)


        def on_button(self):z
            self.destroy()


    w = SampleApp()
    w.resizable(width=True, height=True)
    w.geometry('{}x{}'.format(100, 90))
    w.mainloop()


display_text()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see a way to change the text without updating the existent or replacing the widget.

But you can get the previous text to append the new one, like in the example below, using the method `config()` to update the widget :

```
w = SampleApp()
w.resizable(width=True, height=True)
w.geometry('{}x{}'.format(100, 90))
w.label.config(text=w.label['text']+'\nnew text')
w.mainloop()
```

Or even directly the shorcut :

```
w.label['text'] += '\nnew text'
```

By the way, you should not mix class inside function. You'd better define the class first, then instance it and call the `mainloop()` method to display the root widget.

---

EDIT : Here is a way to update the text with a method in the class bind to a button

```
import tkinter as tk

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text='Enter text')
        self.label.pack(side = 'top', pady = 5)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text='update', command=self.on_button)
        self.button.pack()

    def on_button(self):
        self.label['text'] +='\nNew New Text'


w = SampleApp()
w.resizable(width=True, height=True)
w.geometry('{}x{}'.format(100, 90))
w.label.config(text=w.label['text']+'\nnew text')
w.mainloop()
```

Comment: is there a way to do it so once the widget  has been displayed you can still change the text? It does matter whether it replaces the previous text for now.

Comment: @Daniel you mean if the user can change the text ?

Comment: kind of. So the widget has been displayed, but I would like it so the text on the widget changes without having to close the widget create a second widget

Comment: @Daniel you need to define methods in your class to do that, you cannot call this method after mainloop() if you did so. I updated the example

Comment: Would you mind showing me how? I am very new to tkinter and haven't had much experience with classes...